# How to set adapter for recyclerview with Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I want to use databinding for recyclerview. I created a model with BindignAdapter annotation. But after that I don't know what should I do and I didn't find any solution.
I want to set some data for recyclerview adapter and set the adapter as recyclerview adapter and show data in the recyclerview.

This is my MainActivity XML file(This line has an error:`android:recyclerUser="@{dog.recyclerViewBinder()}"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="dog"
            type="com.hooman.databinding.DogModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:recyclerUser="@{dog.recyclerViewBinder()}"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my model class:

```
class DogModel(var dogName:String, var dogImage:String?, var dogBreed:String,var context: Context){

    @BindingAdapter("android:loadImage")
    fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView,dogImage:String?){
        Picasso.get().load(dogImage).into(imageView)
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:recyclerUser")
    fun recyclerViewBinder(recyclerView: RecyclerView,dogList: MutableList<DogModel>){
        var dogAdapter = DogAdapter(dogList)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        recyclerView.adapter = dogAdapter
    }

}
```

This is recyclerview's adapter:

```
class DogAdapter(var dogList:List<DogModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DogAdapter.DogViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DogViewHolder {
        val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<RvDogItemBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),R.layout.rv_dog_item,parent,false)
        return DogViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DogViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.dog = dogList[position]
        holder.view.executePendingBindings()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dogList.size
    }

    inner class DogViewHolder(var view: RvDogItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root)
}
```

This is rv_dog_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="dog"
            type="com.hooman.databinding.DogModel" />
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_dog"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:loadImage="@{dog.dogImage}"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_dogName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img_dog"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img_dog"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="@{dog.dogName}"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_dogBreed"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_dogName"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/txt_dogName"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/txt_dogName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:text="@{dog.dogBreed}"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And this is mainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var adapter:DogAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
        var model = DogModel("Foo Dog",null,"Husky",this)
        binding.dog = model
        
    }
}
```

So what I should I do next and what did I make a mistake?